# not able to change text color and text background of output in visual studio 2010

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

how to change text color and text background of output in visual studio 2010?
`textcolor() ,textbackground(), textmode()` functions are not working.
is there any alternative?

Comment: What exactly do you mean "not working"? Doesn't compile? Crashes? Works fine except it always uses the normal colours? Have you tried something very simple like [this example](http://www.programmingsimplified.com/c/conio.h/textcolor)?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/3662/ look these examples

Comment: 'textcolor': identifier not found
Similarly for other functions as well.

Comment: did you add `#include<stdio.h>  #include<conio.h>`

Comment: They were functions available in Borland DOS compilers in the previous century, minus a decade.  They are not standard functions and are not supported by MSVC.  Use the Windows console api functions instead.  Or find a more up-to-date book.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question correctly, and you're talking about changing colors in your c/c++ *console* application.
You can use the [SetConsoleAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686047%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to change the color in the console. Here is an **[example](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/code/216345/add-a-little-color-to-your-console-text)**